# How to filter a Query Sql so that it shows only one value when more rows of the same table have two identical values?

Tags: sql, database

Example:
I have a table "person" with 6 columns: id, name, lastname, age, job, genre.
I need to make a query SELECT so that it shows only one value when a person has both the same age and job.

Person:

```
+--------+------------+--------+--------+---------+
| id     | name       |lastname| age    | job     |
+--------+------------+--------+--------+---------+
|    101 | francesco  | pieri  | 18     | soldier | 
|    102 | martin     | gofman | 25     | grocer  | 
|    103 | paulina    | arani  | 44     | engineer| 
|    104 | george     | gobelt | 25     | grocer  |
|    105 | marcus     | derona | 18     | soldier |
+--------+------------+--------+--------+---------+
```

I want the result to show up something like this

```
+--------+------------+--------+--------+---------+
| id     | name       |lastname| age    | job     |
+--------+------------+--------+--------+---------+
|    101 | francesco  | pieri  | 18     | soldier | 
|    102 | martin     | gofman | 25     | grocer  | 
|    103 | paulina    | arani  | 44     | engineer| 
+--------+------------+--------+--------+---------+
```

I don't care about the order or the way the row are grouped, just need that a row with same age and job is shown ONCE.

I tried something with partition by and row number, but only found examples with conditions on a single field and I don't know how to merge it with my personal case.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` for this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by age, job order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```